# Trello API (Ruby/Rails) getting user's cards, boards, lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trello

I want to get particular data from Trello (using Trello API) knowing only user's trello id. I need to get all user's cards that has particular list names, and for all cards that meets requirements I need to get: card shortLink, list name, board name. The problem is I need to reduce waiting time. The only reasonable solution is to use less API requests. Here is my code:

```
userCards = JSON.parse(@a.get('/members/'+trello_id+'/cards?fields=shortLink,labels').body)
userCards.each do |card|
        list = JSON.parse(@a.get('/cards/'+card['id']+'/list?fields=name').body)
        if LIST.include?(list['name'].upcase)
            board = JSON.parse(@a.get('/cards/'+card['id']+'/board?fields=name').body)
        end
end
```

If you have any idea how to make this code work faster, I will be more than happy to hear that.